# Check whether a row already exist in MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm writing a function that connects to Oracle MySQL to check for a specific row but it doesn't seem to work ! Could some one tell me how can I check whether a row already exist in DB

```
 private bool groupAlreadyHasAdmin(string grp) {
 try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            strCmd = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usergroup=@groupname AND privelege=2 LIMIT 1";
            MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(strCmd, myConn);
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("groupname", grp);
            if (myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {                    
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {                    
                return false;
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception E) { MessageBox.Show(E.Message); }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("groupname", grp);` should be `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupname", grp);`, just off the top of my head.  Also, are you getting an error of any kind?

Comment: almost had a heart attack reading `Oracle MySQL`, still not used to it!

Comment: Are you sure ? I'm using Oracle Mysql I used to work in this way since a while and it works even when i don't add @

Comment: what is the error exceptions?

Comment: the function returns always False @spajce

Comment: Try `var datareader = myCmd.ExecuteQuery()` then check if it has any results

Comment: same thing @TyrionLannister it return always false even if there is an existing row

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are using ExecuteReader, and ExecuteNonQuery. You may just prefer to use a simple Exists query, and then do ExecuteScalar, to make things simple. You can use the following command in your case:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()){
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE usergroup=@groupname AND privelege=2 LIMIT 1)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("groupName", groupName);
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    //result will be 1 if it exists, and 0 if it does not..
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could even remove the select exists from the front and it would still work..

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a workaround to this using these lines of code:

```
...
return myCmd.ExecuteReader().Read();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the correct English spelling is "privilege".  Perhaps this query would work:

```
strCmd = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usergroup=@groupname AND privilege=2 LIMIT 1";
```

Also, you can just do `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT *` -- no reason to bring back data you are not going to use.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try: Get the number of rows first.

```
...
return myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
```